# Calculate when the next hour will start

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I calculate time in epoch ms, when the next hour will start? I mean for example now I've a 19.45, next hour is - 20.00. I want to get this time (20.00 in epoch) and store it as attribute. If now time is 20.12, next hour is - 21.00 etc. So not just simple add one hour to current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with an `UpdateAttribute` processor:

- `next-hour`: `${now():plus(3599999):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH"):toDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH"):toNumber()}`

Example:

- `now()` => `1696323223639`
- `next-hour` => `1696323600000`